# How i can set a Date/Time field to be required if a People/group field contain a value

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, date-time, list-form

I am working on a custom list inside sharepoint online classic UI. and inside the custom list i have 2 fields:-

1. "ResponsibilityOwner" --> People/Group which allow single value.
2. "ResponsibilityAssignedDate" --> Date only.

now i want to force the "ResponsibilityAssignedDate" to be required in-case the "ResponsibilityOwner" is not empty.

so inside the new/edit list forms i added this script, to check if the "ResponsibilityOwner" contain a user value:-

```
function PreSaveItem(){
var result = true;
var owner = $("input[id*='ResponsibilityOwner_']");
var attr  = owner.attr('value');
alert(attr);
if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false || attr !== "[]") {
    

}
return result;
```

}

but i did not find any way that can allow me to check if the "ResponsibilityAssignedDate" contain a date value or not. as when i select a date from the calendar, i can not find how this is stored inside the related "ResponsibilityAssignedDate" input field?

here are the 2 fields:-
[image]

so can anyone advice on this please?

Comment: Better use `PreSaveAction` as explained in the answer. In this function check for `if ($('[id$="_$ClientPeoplePicker_HiddenInput"]').val() != '[]' && $('[id$="_$DateTimeFieldDate"]').val() === "") return false;`

Comment: @SteveT you approach of using `PreSaveAction` worked well for me,, i am not sure why my original `PreSaveItem` was not able to catch the date value?

Comment: @Steve T your above code worked for me,, if u can add your comment as a reply so i can accept it.. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Better use `PreSaveAction` . In this function check for:

```
if ($('[id$="_$ClientPeoplePicker_HiddenInput"]').val() != '[]' &&  $('[id$="_$DateTimeFieldDate"]').val() === "") { return false; }
```

(depending on the number of peolplepickers and date fields in your form you might have to adjust the selectors)